# Como realizar a comunicação entre microserviços (microservices)?

Tags: microsserviços

[***Microservices***](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) é um tipo de padrão arquitetural onde uma aplicação é dividida em aplicações menores independentes que se comunicam para realizar o trabalho completo do sistema.

A forma comum de comunicação que geralmente se faz referência é usando HTTP.

Entretanto, HTTP não parece adequado se o volume de dados for grande ou se o modelo de comunicação exigir troca de dados contínua na mesma comunicação. Por outro lado, o uso de sockets parece não ter um bom custo-benefício, além de ser mais propenso a erros introduzidos pela complexidade de uma abordagem de baixo nível.

Enfim, existem outros métodos, técnicas, protocolos ou tecnologias maduras que resolvam esses problemas, usando ou não HTTP? **(Preferencialmente tecnologias que tenham sido usadas com sucesso para essa finalidade)**

Comment: "Por outro lado, o uso de sockets parece não ter um bom custo-benefício". Custo, no caso, seria de implantação?

Comment: @bacco Seria em relação ao esforço de implementação, dado que pode ser  bem complexo e assim demanda mais desenvolvedores seniors, testes, etc.

Answer (score 13):

Você obrigatoriamente vai ter que levar os dados de um lugar até o outro, e todos estes meios envolvem de uma forma ou de outra, o uso de sockets.

As estratégias que você pode usar dependem muito de cada caso em específico. Dentre as técnicas que você pode usar (e pode combinar várias delas), temos:

- Uso de HTTP padrão (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE e PATCH).
- [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV).
- [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol).
- POST via HTTP com [multipart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages), para uploads.
- [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).
- [Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (também chamado de AJAX reverso) para fazer *server-side pushes*.
- [Websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) para permitir comunicação mais-ou-menos em tempo real via TCP full-duplex e com amplo suporte em navegadores.
- [JMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service).
- [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture).
- Chunking - Ou seja, você corta os dados a serem enviados em pedaços e manda um de cada vez.
- [Multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast).
- [Anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast).
- Sockets TCP customizados - A forma mais padrão de envio de informação, com garantia de ordem de entrega, retransmissão de pacotes que não forem recebidos ou que tenham sido danificados e controle de fluxo e congestionamento automaticamente gerenciados pelo sistema operacional.
- Sockets UDP customizados, aonde os pacotes são enviados e se não estiverem corrompidos são aceitos. Não há preocupação com perdas de pacotes, atrasos, duplicações ou congestionamento, que ficam inteiramente a cargo do desenvolvedor. Ideal para o envio de dados em tempo real, aonde pacotes antigos não são mais necessários (e portanto não devem ser retransmitidos) e a perda de alguns pacotes não é crítica.
- Sockets [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol), que é parecido com o UDP, mas já tem o controle de congestionamento, a garantia de retransmissão e o sequenciamento de pacotes tal como o TCP.
- Sockets [UDP-Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP-Lite), semelhante ao UDP, mas não descarta pacotes danificados em alguns casos (e portanto também aceita pacotes que contenham informação truncada, por exemplo).
- Sockets [DCCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Congestion_Control_Protocol), parecido com o TCP, mas sem garantia de ordenação de pacotes.
- [etc.]

Enfim, todas estas são alternativas "maduras", mas algumas são mais trabalhosas do que outras. Algumas se adaptam a microserviços melhores do que outras. Algumas são mais genéricas enquanto outras são mais específicas para certos nichos e certos problemas. Quanto mais especializado for o seu serviço, mais trabalho a mão você terá que fazer. Eu não sei o que você quer fazer, mas você precisa avaliar o seu caso de acordo com os seguintes critérios:

- As mensagens entre os sistemas devem ser entregues em tempo real? Ou deve-se guardá-las e entregá-las quando for oportuno?
- É preferível enviar-se poucas mensagens grandes ou muitas mensagens pequenas?
- Se uma mensagem for recebida danificada ou parcialmente, deve-se tentar utilizá-la mesmo assim?
- Qual é o impacto de um pacote de dados que se perder? Ele deve ser retransmitido, ou deve-se tocar a bola para frente, prosseguir e deixar o passado no passado?
- Qual é o impacto de pacotes de dados que chegam fora de ordem? Eles devem ser utilizados apenas quando corretamente ordenados ou podem ser utilizados mesmo se estiverem fora de ordem?
- Qual é o impacto de um pacote de dados que atrasa para chegar? Deve-se parar tudo até o pacote ser recebido, deve-se ignorar pacotes que chegam já considerados velhos, ou deve-se proseguir e corrigir-se o passado quando o pacote chegar?
- Se o receptor da mensagem não puder ser alcançado, o que acontece? Deve-se insistir com polling até que ele volte? Deve-se armazenar a mensagem até ele voltar? Quando ele voltar ele deve pedir a mensagem? Ou se ele não for alcançável, esqueça e deixe para lá?
- A comunicação se dá entre um servidor e um navegador web? Entre um servidor e um aplicativo cliente? Ou entre um servidor e um outro servidor?
- A informação flui em um sentido só ou ela flui nos dois sentidos? Se ela flui nos dois sentidos, isso ocorre apenas em um sentido de cada vez ou pode ocorrer nos dois sentidos ao mesmo tempo?
- Uma mesma informação será transmitida apenas para um destinatário específico ou vários destinatários poderão recebê-la? Ou qualquer destinatário dentro de um determinado grupo pode recebê-la?

Enfim, como você pode ver, há muitas particularidades a serem consideradas, e por tal motivo, não há como ser dada uma resposta *one-size-fits-all*. Cada caso é um caso. **A primeira coisa que eu analisaria é se o HTTP simples resolveria. Se não, vale a pena olhar o Ajax e o websockets. Se isso também não servir, então o problema em questão deve ser estudado com detalhes para encontrar-se a solução mais adequada.**

Comment: Interessante a resposta, mas não entendi onde Ajax e Websockets são usados aqui se essas são tecnologias usadas no browser.

Comment: @utluiz Já vi isso acontecendo. O serviço disponibiliza um Ajax e/ou websocket para ser usado pelo browser, mas ocorre que não é usado exclusivamente pelo browser, de forma que um outro serviço (no papel de cliente) também acaba utilizando-o. Normalmente isso é feito quando o serviço servidor é controlado e disponibilizado por uma entidade externa que você não tem como controlar ou influenciar. Mas o foco destas técnicas é sem dúvida conversar com o browser mesmo, e usar para algo diferente disso, normalmente acaba ou sendo gambiarra ou sendo para algum propósito mal-intencionado (ex: spam).

Comment: E muitas vezes, você acaba concluindo que o consumidor do serviço é o browser mesmo. E portanto, cabe aí o Ajax e o websocket.